# Xcode 13.1 issues with table view - items gets removed while reloading sometime

Tags: ios, iphone, ios15, xcode13, swift5

My project after compiled from **Xcode 13.1 and in simulator iOS 15.0 have issues with table view.**

Table view cells gets removed completely for that area and empty space is there which is the background of table view.

After scrolling up down multiple times it's some times displaying or sometimes not.

This happening with multiple section of table view cell.

Any one facing this issue, pls suggest.

Thanks

Chandan

Comment: Did you ensure that reloading happens on the main thread?

Comment: Give more information about the issue.

Comment: @MANISHPATHAK Issue complete section view is missing. I have tried with giving fixed height as well for that area. After debugging that cellforrow is working.

But issue that sections and cells are invisible. It's random not a fixed position.

Comment: @lazarevzubov Yes. It's on main thread.

Issue is not on very first time reload. It's after scrolling the items manually at random position.

Answer (score 0):

please use this in ViewDidLoad()

```
 if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            mainTableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0
        }
```

Comment: No. This change will fix only for the padding issue in every section which is not my issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I found the existing functionality of table view cell is breaking ion Xcode 13.1 due to some cell height calculation and complexity. So after refactor some feature this issue is is fixed now.

Also noticed View.animation affecting and hiding cell item views. Looks animations are also broken.

I have removed the animation while table view scroll to position.

Comment: I solved by removing my attributing string creation with some html content from cellForRowAtIndexpath method. this heavy calculation causing problem here enabling tablew view to load multiple times in between